# Get distance for Tuio object from camera

Tags: c#

I work with [Tuio](http://www.tuio.org/?software) marker detection to make some motions using Symbols, here is my question I want to get the distance between the camera and tuio object.

I can work with the object position X,Y,Z but function `o.getdistance();` get the distance only between the two float point passed to it. 
How i can get the distance between the object and detection camera ? 
Should i implement my own method ? If answer yes how to make it ? 
Can anyone give me bit of code or link ?